# SQL Query about cumulative sum - Buyer and Received bank account with transactions

Tags: sql

Find the cumulative balance over transactions of the account owned by 'Mike Johnson'.

Output the transaction dates and cumulative balances - columns should be: name, transaction_date, transaction_amount, cumulative_balance

`dim_accounts` table:

- Account_id   J235GBUW
- Name Kailthyn JONES
- City Atlanta
- balance  80

`fact_transactions` table:

- Transaction_id   GB8528338495810340223
- Payer_id UDG445BYY
- Receiver_id  OY1VYB97
- Amount   30
- Transaction_date 2023-08-15 15:00:00

**My attempt**

I started using the following, then maybe added what was paid and deducted what was received. I'm not sure how to list all transactions

```
Select 
    dap.Account_id,
    sum(atp.amount) over (Partition by atpP.Payer_id order by atpP.Transaction_date) as SumPaid,
    sum(atp.amount) over (Partition by atpR.Payer_id order by atpR.Transaction_date) as SumReceived
From
    dim_accounts dap
Join 
    act_transactions atpP on dap.Account_id = atP.Payer_id
Left Join 
    act_transactions atpR on dap.Account_id = atpR.Received_id
```

Comment: Sample data for all tables and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: There is always a Payer_Id and Receiver_Id, right (AccountA paying to AccountB).

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].